# uninitialized constant Faker::Date Updating to rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had a working application when I tried to update from rails 5.0 to 5.1. (I've been updating from 4.2 to 5.0)

It doesn't work it anymore, running commands like:

```
rails server
```

yields an error. I don't know how to fix this, and I coudn't find any information, it's weird because it points to the faker's code, not to mine.

This is the console output

> /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in
>   `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while
>   trying to load the gem 'faker'. (Bundler::GemRequireError) Gem Load
>   Error is: uninitialized constant Faker::Date Backtrace for gem load
>   error is:
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/faker-1.8.1/lib/faker/time.rb:2:in`
>   '
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/faker-1.8.1/lib/faker/time.rb:1:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/faker-1.8.1/lib/faker.rb:214:in`
>   block in '
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/faker-1.8.1/lib/faker.rb:214:in
>   `each'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/faker-1.8.1/lib/faker.rb:214:in`
>   '
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in
>   `require'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in`
>   block (2 levels) in require'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in
>   `each'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in`
>   block in require'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in
>   `each'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in`
>   require'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:106:in
>   `require'
>   /home/gaston/Workspace/cloud9workspace/projects/time/config/application.rb:7:in`
>   '
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:128:in
>   `require'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:128:in`
>   block in perform'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:125:in
>   `tap'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:125:in`
>   perform'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in
>   `run'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in`
>   invoke_command'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor.rb:369:in
>   `dispatch'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in`
>   perform'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in
>   `invoke'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in`
>   '
>   /home/gaston/Workspace/cloud9workspace/projects/time/bin/rails:9:in
>   `require'
>   /home/gaston/Workspace/cloud9workspace/projects/time/bin/rails:9:in`
>   '
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in
>   `load'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`
>   call'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in
>   `call'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in`
>   run'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in`
>   load'
>   /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   /home/gaston/Workspace/cloud9workspace/projects/time/bin/spring:13:in`
>   require'
>   /home/gaston/Workspace/cloud9workspace/projects/time/bin/spring:13:in
>   `<top (required)>' bin/rails:3:in`load' bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
>   Bundler Error Backtrace:
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90:in`
>   block (2 levels) in require'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in
>   `each'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in`
>   block in require'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in
>   `each'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in`
>   require'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:106:in
>   `require'
>           from /home/gaston/Workspace/cloud9workspace/projects/time/config/application.rb:7:in`
>   '
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:128:in
>   `require'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:128:in`
>   block in perform'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:125:in
>   `tap'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:125:in`
>   perform'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in
>   `run'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in`
>   invoke_command'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor.rb:369:in
>   `dispatch'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in`
>   perform'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in
>   `invoke'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in`
>   '
>           from /home/gaston/Workspace/cloud9workspace/projects/time/bin/rails:9:in
>   `require'
>           from /home/gaston/Workspace/cloud9workspace/projects/time/bin/rails:9:in`
>   '
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in
>   `load'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`
>   call'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in
>   `call'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in`
>   run'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in`
>   load'
>           from /home/gaston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>           from /home/gaston/Workspace/cloud9workspace/projects/time/bin/spring:13:in`
>   require'
>           from /home/gaston/Workspace/cloud9workspace/projects/time/bin/spring:13:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>           from bin/rails:3:in`load'
>           from bin/rails:3:in `'

This are my files:
spring.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# This file loads spring without using Bundler, in order to be fast.
# It gets overwritten when you run the `spring binstub` command.

unless defined?(Spring)
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'bundler'

  if (match = Bundler.default_lockfile.read.match(/^GEM$.*?^    (?:  )*spring \((.*?)\)$.*?^$/m))
    Gem.paths = { 'GEM_PATH' => [Bundler.bundle_path.to_s, *Gem.path].uniq.join(Gem.path_separator) }
    gem 'spring', match[1]
    require 'spring/binstub'
  end
end
```

Faker was already included in the gemfile, I've updated to the last version.
gemfile

```
gem 'faker', '~> 1.8', '>= 1.8.1'
```

this is my application.rb, (the first 7 lines)
application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups) 
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem while updating. I've done the process from scratch and now it works. It had nothing to do with faker.